# How to restart only one war in ear in WebLogic?

Tags: deployment, weblogic

I have two war files in my ear.
In JBoss I can restart one web application via jmx-console.
Not whole ear, but only one web application.
Administrative Console from WebLogic allows to restart whole ear only.
I cannot restart only one war in ear.
Why?

Answer (score 2):

Within the packaged EAR, it is not possible to only deploy individual WAR.

But if you follow the directory structure required for Weblogic "[Split Development Directory](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/splitcreate.html#wp1100718)", then you can build your individual webapp within the Enterprise App, and get only that webapp reloaded. I'm not sure how this works from admin console.

This uses OOTB ant tasks available with Weblogic.

Essentially this becomes [an exploded directory instead of packaged EAR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/deployment/deployunits.html#wp1045820).

Comment: But I need to restart one application in ear, not to deploy one application.